# How do I open app-drawer ONLY with icon menu in Polymer 1.6?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

This is my first taste of polymer, so am starting with Layout.
I used the `polymer-cli` to start a `app-drawer-template` boilerplate, then am trying layout the header (which should include the navigation and search).

Currently the app-drawer shows by default.
[How app-drawer currently shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxAk1.jpg)

I wanted the `app-drawer` to only show(open/visible) when the menu icon is clicked in mobile(narrow) viewport size. How can I achieve this?

Comment: So you want to have a drawer that doesn't display on desktop viewport sizes and that opens with the icon button on mobile devices?

Comment: Exactly, thats the behaviour I want.

Comment: You might want to check the [shop case study code](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/toolbox/case-study), they use a drawer only for mobile devices and a tab-based navigation for desktops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the `<app-draw-layout>`'s [narrow](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-layout?active=app-drawer-layout#property-narrow) property and hide the `<app-drawer>` accordingly.

```
<app-drawer-layout narrow$={{isNarrow}}>
    <app-drawer hidden$="[[!isNarrow]]">
```

...

```
properties: {
    isNarrow: Boolean
}
```

See https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/toolbox/app-layout for more ideas.

Comment: The reference Link actually solved the problem for me. Thanks